# What is this code fragment for?

Tags: code

Taking a look at the code of the package `ifxetex`, I found the following:

```
\begingroup\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\endgroup
\expandafter\ifx\csname ProvidesPackage\endcsname\relax\else
  \ProvidesPackage{ifxetex}
    [2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional]
\fi
```

I perfectly understand someone may want to check if LaTeX is being used or not before invoking `\ProvidesPackage`, so as to make the file usable by plain TeX too. However, I don't see the point in the first line. What is the reason behind a group containing only three `\expandafter`s which seem to be there exclusively to get the `\if` done before the `\endgroup`? Why not simply remove that group?

Comment: Fine-grained expansion control. I think there's three expandafters because you want two levels of expansion.

Comment: What does that line change in the effect of the code? I mean, suppose I remove it. To me, nothing changes. Obviously, there mus be something changing: I trust a package author knows better than to put a useless line of code in their work. So exactly _what_ changes @1010011010?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A group is started, then

```
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\endgroup
\expandafter\ifx\csname ProvidesPackage\endcsname\relax\else
  \ProvidesPackage{ifxetex}
    [2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional]
\fi
```

remains. Now the first `\expandafter` is expanded, which causes the third to act, which expands the fourth and finally `\csname ProvidesPackage\endcsname` forms the `\ProvidesPackage` token, making it equivalent to `\relax` if not defined.

Now we're left with

```
\expandafter\endgroup
\ifx\ProvidesPackage\relax\else
  \ProvidesPackage{ifxetex}
    [2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional]
\fi
```

The remaining `\expandafter` expands `\ifx`. If `\ProvidesPackage` had no previous definition, the test returns true and

```
\endgroup\else\ProvidesPackage{ifxetex}[2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional]\fi
```

remains. The group is closed, undoing the assignment of a meaning to `\ProvidesPackage`. Then `\else` is expanded, which means that TeX skips all tokens up to the matching `\fi` which eventually disappears.

If there was a previous definition for `\ProvidesPackage` existed, TeX skips all tokens up to and including `\else`, so we remain with

```
\endgroup\ProvidesPackage{ifxetex}[2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional]\fi
```

The group is closed and `\ProvidesPackage` is executed (with the necessary expansion steps). The trailing `\fi` has null expansion.

The moral is that if `\ProvidesPackage` was not defined when the code is found, it won't be at the end of the process.

Without the `\begingroup\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\endgroup` trickery, the code would end up with `\ProvidesPackage` being equivalent to `\relax`, if not defined previously.